# Asynchronous multiple web scrapers in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, sleep

I have a legacy code base of many specialized web scrapers, all relying on making synchronous requests to web servers, running `while True` with a `sleep` statement at the end. This code base is in Python 2, and it's likely not feasible to move to Python 3 and take advantage of Python 3 async features.

Ideally I'd like to rewrite this set of many individual web scraping scripts as a single pipeline featuring the following

- asynchronous web requests (in Python 2)
- asynchronous writes to csv
- non-blocking `sleep` statements so that each individual page is scraped at a set frequency

This seems like an easy problem in Python 3 between `asyncio` and coroutines generally. Can someone recommend how I'd do this/some example resources for doing this in Python 2.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The threading module https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html could be helpful here. You can write to separate files from each thread and combine them after all the threads finish.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put each function in a different file then when you want them to all go you can do.

```
import os
os.system('python file1.py')
os.system('python file2.py')
os.system('python file3.py')
os.system('python file4.py')
```